# Concat multiple C++ strings at once?

Tags: c++, string

I'm new to C++ strings. Is there a way to concatenate more than two strings at once? Or I have to concat two strings at the time? My concern is that it probably needs to allocate memory on each operation, instead of only once for the final result.

Remember something like that in java, wonder if there is a method for that somewhere in std. Actually, std::stringstream might be it, but I don't know how exactly it works.

Comment: Unless you have cause not to(you profiled and found the performance unacceptable) just use `operator +` like: `auto foo = string1 + string2 + "some text" + string3;`

Comment: Do you just want to concatinate a bunch of random strings? If so,then just use the "+" operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, to avoid expensive memory waste use the `stringstream`

> std::stringstream might be it, but I don't know how exactly it works.

this is how it works: include the sstream, create an object, append to it as much as you need using the stream operator **<<** get the result as string calling the function **str**

example:

```
#include <sstream>
std::stringstream mySS;

mySS << "Hello" << " World!" << "end!!" << " Foo";
```

and when you are done

```
std::string stringResult = mySS.str();
```

Comment: So it actually holds all strings as is until the .str() call? This is what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: exactly, you append and append things until you need it and then call str().... more or less like the StringBuilder in java....

Comment: Sorry for an extra question, I wonder how can I actually check if it works like that. Opening it in debugger I guess?

Answer (score 9):

You can `reserve` the required space beforehand, avoiding reallocations.

```
std::string s0{/*...*/}, s1{/*...*/}, s2{/*...*/};
std::string sink;

sink.reserve(s0.size() + s1.size() + s2.size() + 1);
sink += s0;
sink += s1;
sink += s2;
```

---

You can make this nicer with a variadic `string_cat` function. Here's a C++17 implementation:

```
template <typename... Strings>
std::string string_cat(Strings&&... strings)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve((strings.size() + ...) + 1);
    ((result += std::forward<Strings>(strings)), ...);
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
using namespace std::literals;
auto res = string_cat("a"s, "b"s, "c"s);
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bSJHX6dBhayTJxyt)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that each concatenation could require an allocation.  Consider an expression like this, where each variable is a string:

```
a = b + c + d + e;
```

This requires three concatenation operations and three temporaries, each of which requires a new allocation.

A simple solution is to use `std::ostringstream`, which should not require as many reallocations:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << b << c << d << e;
a = ss.str();
```

However, if we are concatenating only strings, we can do one better, and allocate exactly the right size of string (C++11-compatible implementation):

```
std::size_t total_string_size()
{
    return 1;
}

template <typename... T>
std::size_t total_string_size(std::string const &s, T const & ...tail)
{
    return s.size() + total_string_size(tail...);
}

void concat_strings_impl(std::string &) { }

template <typename... T>
void concat_strings_impl(std::string &out, std::string const &s, T const & ...tail)
{
    out += s;
    concat_strings_impl(out, tail...);
}

template <typename... T>
void concat_strings(std::string &out, T const & ...strings)
{
    out.clear();
    out.reserve(total_string_size(strings...));
    concat_strings_impl(out, strings...);
}
```

Now we can call `concat_strings(a, b, c, d, e)` to perform the equivalent of `a = b + c + d + e;` in a single reallocation. ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/227b4c45895ca161))

Comment: What makes you think `std::stringstream` doesn't use so many allocations?

Comment: @Galik I meant reallocations. It should be allocating a bit of extra room like `std::vector` does, whereas a simple `+` concatenation operation *requires* a new allocation for the string temporary. So it would be more accurate to say that stringstream will not require more reallocations, but generally should require fewer.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to avoid multiple allocations is to tell the string how big it needs to become before concatenating.

For example, to join together all the strings stored in a vector (like a list):

```
std::string join(std::vector<std::string> const& v)
{
    std::string r; // return string

    // add up all the string sizes
    std::size_t size = 0;
    for(auto const& s: v)
        size += s.size();

    // reserve that much space all at once (one allocation)
    r.reserve(size);

    // now do the concatenations
    for(auto const& s: v)
        r += s;

    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* concatenate multiple strings - no problem:

```
std::string hello = "Hello";
std::string cruel = "cruel";
std::string world = "world";
std::string result = hello + " " + cruel + " " + world;
```

Results in `result` holding the string "Hello cruel world".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the c-style strings (ie `char*`), then you can allocate once and cat a number of times.  The `strcat` function takes a pointer to a destination address as a first argument.  Thus if you make your destination string large enough, there will only be one alloc.  Thus

```
char* dest = new char[100];
dest[0] = 0; //Zero length string to start
strcat(dest, str1);
strcat(dest, str2);
strcat(dest, str3);
```

If on the other hand you use `std::string` then `+` can be chained `string1 + string2 + string3`.

Comment: It seems like his question is about the performance of multiple concatenations -- does it create a new intermediate string for each step in the chain, rather than combine them all at once?

Comment: Beware of [Schlemiel the Painter](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm).